# consulta nodos en C

Tags: c, nodos

Como puedo Insertar un nodo en la i-esima posición, asumiendo que el primer nodo está en la posición 0 y Eliminar un nodo en la i-esima posición, asumiendo que el primer nodo está en la posición 0 en C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Nodo
{int valor;
struct Nodo * sig;
};
 typedef struct Nodo LNodo;
 typedef LNodo *Lista;

 Lista Crear_nodo (int valor_nodo)
 {

    Lista re;
    re = (Lista) malloc(sizeof(LNodo));

    if(re!= NULL)
 {

    re -> valor = valor_nodo;
    re-> sig = NULL;

}
return re
}

int main()
{
Lista L = NULL;
L = Crear_nodo(1);

}
Lista L = NULL;
L = Crear_nodo(1);

int primero = 5, final = 8, contador = 0; 

while (conbtador < 5)
{

L = Agregar_Nodo(L,contador);
contador++;

}

Lista Agregar_Nodo( Lista L, int val)
{

while ( re-> sig!=NULL)
{

    re= re-> sig;
}
re-> sig = Crear_nodo(val);

return(L);
}
```

Ahí esta lo que llevo hasta el momento en lo que respecta al código que necesito, al parecer me falta la eliminación de la i-esima posición, asumiendo que el nodo este en la posición 0.

Comment: Tenés algún código que hayas escrito intentando algo?, la idea es que te ayudemos a resolver un problema.

Comment: @JavierSnachez ahí esta lo que hice